# Computation failed in `stat_summary()`: when trying to add error bars and mean; ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe from which I wish to present using ggplot the reldif on the y axis and the landscape on the x axis.

I have used geom_dotplot and have the following figure.

[image]

The code for this plot is:

```
p<-ggplot(sum.qmerge, aes(x=landscape,y=reldif))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis="y",stackdir="center")+
  theme_minimal()
```

This is fine, what I want to do is add error bars, using:

```
p + stat_summary(fun.data="mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1), 
                 geom="crossbar", width=0.5)
```

but I receive the error:

"Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:"

How can I fix this issue?

The dput code for the dataframe used for plotting is:

```
structure(list(theta = list(`1` = 20, `8` = 20, `15` = 20, `22` = 20, 
    `29` = 20, `36` = 20, `43` = 20, `2` = 40, `9` = 40, `16` = 40, 
    `23` = 40, `30` = 40, `37` = 40, `44` = 40, `3` = 60, `10` = 60, 
    `17` = 60, `24` = 60, `31` = 60, `38` = 60, `45` = 60, `4` = 80, 
    `11` = 80, `18` = 80, `25` = 80, `32` = 80, `39` = 80, `46` = 80, 
    `5` = 100, `12` = 100, `19` = 100, `26` = 100, `33` = 100, 
    `40` = 100, `47` = 100, `6` = 120, `13` = 120, `20` = 120, 
    `27` = 120, `34` = 120, `41` = 120, `48` = 120, `7` = 140, 
    `14` = 140, `21` = 140, `28` = 140, `35` = 140, `42` = 140, 
    `49` = 140, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 60, 80, 
    100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 60, 
    80, 100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 
    60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, `1` = 20, 
    `2` = 40, `3` = 60, `4` = 80, `5` = 100, `6` = 120, `7` = 140, 
    `8` = 20, `9` = 40, `10` = 60, `11` = 80, `12` = 100, `13` = 120, 
    `14` = 140, `15` = 20, `16` = 40, `17` = 60, `18` = 80, `19` = 100, 
    `20` = 120, `21` = 140, `22` = 20, `23` = 40, `24` = 60, 
    `25` = 80, `26` = 100, `27` = 120, `28` = 140, `29` = 20, 
    `30` = 40, `31` = 60, `32` = 80, `33` = 100, `34` = 120, 
    `35` = 140, `36` = 20, `37` = 40, `38` = 60, `39` = 80, `40` = 100, 
    `41` = 120, `42` = 140, `43` = 20, `44` = 40, `45` = 60, 
    `46` = 80, `47` = 100, `48` = 120, `49` = 140), beta = list(
    `1` = 50, `8` = 66.6666666666667, `15` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `22` = 100, `29` = 116.666666666667, `36` = 133.333333333333, 
    `43` = 150, `2` = 50, `9` = 66.6666666666667, `16` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `23` = 100, `30` = 116.666666666667, `37` = 133.333333333333, 
    `44` = 150, `3` = 50, `10` = 66.6666666666667, `17` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `24` = 100, `31` = 116.666666666667, `38` = 133.333333333333, 
    `45` = 150, `4` = 50, `11` = 66.6666666666667, `18` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `25` = 100, `32` = 116.666666666667, `39` = 133.333333333333, 
    `46` = 150, `5` = 50, `12` = 66.6666666666667, `19` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `26` = 100, `33` = 116.666666666667, `40` = 133.333333333333, 
    `47` = 150, `6` = 50, `13` = 66.6666666666667, `20` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `27` = 100, `34` = 116.666666666667, `41` = 133.333333333333, 
    `48` = 150, `7` = 50, `14` = 66.6666666666667, `21` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `28` = 100, `35` = 116.666666666667, `42` = 133.333333333333, 
    `49` = 150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 66.6666666666667, 
    66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 
    66.6666666666667, 66.6666666666667, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 
    83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 83.3333333333333, 
    83.3333333333333, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 116.666666666667, 
    116.666666666667, 116.666666666667, 116.666666666667, 116.666666666667, 
    116.666666666667, 116.666666666667, 133.333333333333, 133.333333333333, 
    133.333333333333, 133.333333333333, 133.333333333333, 133.333333333333, 
    133.333333333333, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, `1` = 50, 
    `2` = 50, `3` = 50, `4` = 50, `5` = 50, `6` = 50, `7` = 50, 
    `8` = 66.6666666666667, `9` = 66.6666666666667, `10` = 66.6666666666667, 
    `11` = 66.6666666666667, `12` = 66.6666666666667, `13` = 66.6666666666667, 
    `14` = 66.6666666666667, `15` = 83.3333333333333, `16` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `17` = 83.3333333333333, `18` = 83.3333333333333, `19` = 83.3333333333333, 
    `20` = 83.3333333333333, `21` = 83.3333333333333, `22` = 100, 
    `23` = 100, `24` = 100, `25` = 100, `26` = 100, `27` = 100, 
    `28` = 100, `29` = 116.666666666667, `30` = 116.666666666667, 
    `31` = 116.666666666667, `32` = 116.666666666667, `33` = 116.666666666667, 
    `34` = 116.666666666667, `35` = 116.666666666667, `36` = 133.333333333333, 
    `37` = 133.333333333333, `38` = 133.333333333333, `39` = 133.333333333333, 
    `40` = 133.333333333333, `41` = 133.333333333333, `42` = 133.333333333333, 
    `43` = 150, `44` = 150, `45` = 150, `46` = 150, `47` = 150, 
    `48` = 150, `49` = 150), q_mean = c(0.0206766962630277, 0.0221165556788245, 
0.0231069873661408, 0.0231538499729732, 0.0249907999246934, 0.0253294962365531, 
0.0261334161609693, 0.0248827777777778, 0.0273111111111111, 0.0286533333333333, 
0.0307361111111111, 0.0309588888888889, 0.0316633333333333, 0.0323633333333333, 
0.0246661111111111, 0.02865, 0.0314444444444444, 0.0339211111111111, 
0.0349105555555556, 0.0361416666666667, 0.0372383333333333, 0.0237388888888889, 
0.0276955555555556, 0.0306294444444444, 0.0358011111111111, 0.0385916666666667, 
0.0412177777777778, 0.0404733333333333, 0.021115, 0.0274627777777778, 
0.0326177777777778, 0.0347333333333333, 0.0366833333333333, 0.0407777777777778, 
0.0449205555555556, 0.0208083333333333, 0.0263488888888889, 0.0300833333333333, 
0.0332588888888889, 0.0371888888888889, 0.0414677777777778, 0.0419788888888889, 
0.0207083333333333, 0.0251827777777778, 0.0278094444444444, 0.0330488888888889, 
0.0359972222222222, 0.03977, 0.0430377777777778, 0.0131022222222222, 
0.0167977777777778, 0.0179038888888889, 0.0174394444444444, 0.0180055555555556, 
0.01754, 0.0167294444444444, 0.01422, 0.0191472222222222, 0.0214005555555556, 
0.0211616666666667, 0.0213133333333333, 0.0208872222222222, 0.0209327777777778, 
0.015125, 0.02147, 0.0245283333333333, 0.0250105555555556, 0.0236572222222222, 
0.0231944444444444, 0.0238983333333333, 0.0158844444444444, 0.0231816666666667, 
0.0258088888888889, 0.029085, 0.027815, 0.0265883333333333, 0.0254861111111111, 
0.0169683333333333, 0.0259338888888889, 0.02949, 0.0306477777777778, 
0.0317238888888889, 0.0302772222222222, 0.0305205555555556, 0.0180888888888889, 
0.0257816666666667, 0.0311427777777778, 0.0332327777777778, 0.032665, 
0.0337477777777778, 0.0330983333333333, 0.018765, 0.027955, 0.0327783333333333, 
0.0364672222222222, 0.036935, 0.0354366666666667, 0.0351138888888889, 
0.0119161111111111, 0.015885, 0.0167766666666667, 0.01717, 0.0179883333333333, 
0.0162333333333333, 0.0172066666666667, 0.0134855555555556, 0.0184816666666667, 
0.0203311111111111, 0.0205311111111111, 0.0207761111111111, 0.0207527777777778, 
0.0200272222222222, 0.015265, 0.0221483333333333, 0.0236766666666667, 
0.0240661111111111, 0.0242711111111111, 0.0234722222222222, 0.0218033333333333, 
0.0159311111111111, 0.0241822222222222, 0.0266816666666667, 0.0273227777777778, 
0.0282327777777778, 0.0276722222222222, 0.0251005555555556, 0.0169866666666667, 
0.0258833333333333, 0.0295088888888889, 0.0294722222222222, 0.0308116666666667, 
0.0297061111111111, 0.0301666666666667, 0.0174238888888889, 0.0264605555555556, 
0.0305894444444444, 0.0327372222222222, 0.0344022222222222, 0.0331338888888889, 
0.0315288888888889, 0.0185688888888889, 0.0273933333333333, 0.0322227777777778, 
0.0371105555555556, 0.0367766666666667, 0.0354, 0.0339311111111111
), anq = c(0.00891992277851751, 0.0100949282065296, 0.0109308363689411, 
0.0115919061900097, 0.0124648224053396, 0.0128018184333939, 0.0133982215120548, 
0.0157536805643288, 0.0176796038664676, 0.019123242417343, 0.020422917310474, 
0.0213618503583558, 0.0220818345838128, 0.023017122701185, 0.0172277568811065, 
0.0196027694164573, 0.021256494932688, 0.022606067240547, 0.0237292005888401, 
0.0248361830908026, 0.0255882016695486, 0.0173165200553415, 0.0196456459515033, 
0.0213262917422529, 0.0227226277018576, 0.0239488752427237, 0.0251902696758707, 
0.0262184674601541, 0.0167863747861682, 0.019261915027263, 0.0208388019598675, 
0.0223211429558177, 0.0237161651769306, 0.0247221727616768, 0.0259049734219606, 
0.0163026891162644, 0.0185755258707006, 0.0203551596632459, 0.0218469637800585, 
0.0230478491219177, 0.0242541940369562, 0.0253282758415854, 0.0156098482969398, 
0.0179538876821958, 0.0197263296781327, 0.0212030444084878, 0.0225163707334275, 
0.0235118536940363, 0.0248260963034743, 0.00682542162242726, 
0.0078387468945225, 0.00863075202960186, 0.0093187191603788, 
0.00988476317006889, 0.0104034475413321, 0.0107773113802319, 
0.0120334829009044, 0.0138075363718971, 0.0150789245688621, 0.0161516879919267, 
0.017203427795047, 0.0182729256706651, 0.0190810783337599, 0.0137167899272071, 
0.0156682035944219, 0.0174939574706345, 0.0188852991013382, 0.0201032949191789, 
0.0211309449062086, 0.0220515414700781, 0.0140579171051135, 0.0162326010584276, 
0.0181102094070484, 0.0195208441225406, 0.0207985170843068, 0.0219178196030856, 
0.0227855521289911, 0.0140794747215616, 0.0162257404328566, 0.0181043098822068, 
0.019591891662349, 0.0208060148731012, 0.0219045934803924, 0.0227393657000369, 
0.0138196386098607, 0.015923459272983, 0.0178461201174297, 0.0193522776379522, 
0.0206657571492465, 0.0216880872807155, 0.0225609803149424, 0.0135220360249286, 
0.0155748128707384, 0.0174966610427859, 0.019106973097458, 0.0202676188402391, 
0.0213885628811621, 0.02228007314228, 0.00691906238772986, 0.007982020650592, 
0.00885031167266586, 0.00941743009317581, 0.0100729094502315, 
0.0106025898036063, 0.0109812183803874, 0.0118377634098989, 0.0136359043025696, 
0.0149246079632603, 0.0160757700402892, 0.0170052471694642, 0.018009195947853, 
0.0188381410740389, 0.0135465983428462, 0.0155064849974479, 0.0171940927810518, 
0.0185534416044806, 0.0200136344060557, 0.0210077089592169, 0.0217827056245604, 
0.0140229317957214, 0.0160058411908555, 0.0179818567752585, 0.0193618163527343, 
0.0207369825062728, 0.0216839962712862, 0.0225810731445431, 0.0140396755449986, 
0.0160626410239967, 0.0180102666215891, 0.0195442898849579, 0.0207072563722883, 
0.0217159806175681, 0.0227261747123137, 0.0137294175712153, 0.0158679558264626, 
0.0177081041017557, 0.019294669746572, 0.0205004244968203, 0.0215535759320743, 
0.0225480294030267, 0.0134530416220537, 0.0155971651349776, 0.0173865264839645, 
0.0189188857864315, 0.0201422490114025, 0.0212714303987629, 0.022149590912329
), absdif = c(0.0117567734845102, 0.0120216274722949, 0.0121761509971997, 
0.0115619437829635, 0.0125259775193539, 0.0125276778031592, 0.0127351946489144, 
0.00912909721344894, 0.00963150724464354, 0.00953009091599031, 
0.0103131938006371, 0.00959703853053305, 0.0095814987495205, 
0.00934621063214833, 0.00743835423000463, 0.00904723058354267, 
0.0101879495117564, 0.0113150438705641, 0.0111813549667154, 0.0113054835758641, 
0.0116501316637848, 0.00642236883354734, 0.00804990960405228, 
0.00930315270219158, 0.0130784834092535, 0.014642791423943, 0.0160275081019071, 
0.0142548658731792, 0.00432862521383183, 0.00820086275051474, 
0.0117789758179103, 0.0124121903775156, 0.0129671681564027, 0.0160556050161009, 
0.0190155821335949, 0.00450564421706892, 0.00777336301818827, 
0.00972817367008745, 0.0114119251088304, 0.0141410397669712, 
0.0172135837408216, 0.0166506130473035, 0.00509848503639353, 
0.00722889009558197, 0.00808311476631176, 0.0118458444804011, 
0.0134808514887948, 0.0162581463059637, 0.0182116814743035, 0.00627680059979496, 
0.00895903088325528, 0.00927313685928703, 0.00812072528406564, 
0.00812079238548667, 0.00713655245866788, 0.00595213306421259, 
0.00218651709909562, 0.00533968585032516, 0.00632163098669347, 
0.00500997867473999, 0.00410990553828633, 0.00261429655155715, 
0.00185169944401792, 0.00140821007279295, 0.00580179640557806, 
0.00703437586269885, 0.00612525645421734, 0.00355392730304328, 
0.00206349953823584, 0.0018467918632552, 0.00182652733933095, 
0.00694906560823912, 0.00769867948184048, 0.00956415587745938, 
0.00701648291569317, 0.00467051373024775, 0.00270055898212002, 
0.00288885861177171, 0.00970814845603228, 0.0113856901177932, 
0.0110558861154288, 0.0109178740157877, 0.00837262874182983, 
0.00778118985551869, 0.00426925027902819, 0.00985820739368368, 
0.0132966576603481, 0.0138805001398256, 0.0119992428507535, 0.0120596904970623, 
0.010537353018391, 0.00524296397507137, 0.0123801871292616, 0.0152816722905474, 
0.0173602491247642, 0.0166673811597609, 0.0140481037855045, 0.0128338157466089, 
0.00499704872338125, 0.007902979349408, 0.0079263549940008, 0.00775256990682419, 
0.0079154238831018, 0.00563074352972701, 0.00622544828627928, 
0.00164779214565666, 0.00484576236409709, 0.00540650314785079, 
0.00445534107082191, 0.00377086394164687, 0.00274358182992477, 
0.00118908114818329, 0.00171840165715375, 0.00664184833588546, 
0.00648257388561482, 0.00551266950663054, 0.00425747670505538, 
0.00246451326300533, 2.06277087729627e-05, 0.00190817931538969, 
0.00817638103136668, 0.00869980989140814, 0.00796096142504345, 
0.00749579527150501, 0.00598822595093601, 0.00251948241101249, 
0.00294699112166802, 0.00982069230933666, 0.0114986222672998, 
0.00992793233726436, 0.0101044102943784, 0.007990130493543, 0.00744049195435297, 
0.00369447131767358, 0.0105925997290929, 0.0128813403426887, 
0.0134425524756502, 0.0139017977254019, 0.0115803129568146, 0.00898085948586215, 
0.00511584726683514, 0.0117961681983557, 0.0148362512938133, 
0.0181916697691241, 0.0166344176552642, 0.0141285696012371, 0.0117815201987821
), reldif = c(0.568600192939558, 0.543557850818741, 0.526946711151178, 
0.499352971383135, 0.501223552551311, 0.494588510018625, 0.487314577262756, 
0.366884167635091, 0.352658930845369, 0.332599729501756, 0.335539970016208, 
0.309992989896269, 0.302605497932008, 0.288790111200381, 0.30156169314643, 
0.315784662601838, 0.323998394366813, 0.333569376118043, 0.320285792900711, 
0.312810244201911, 0.312853197792188, 0.270542099236724, 0.290657090734456, 
0.303732335696313, 0.365309427650544, 0.379428842771142, 0.388849398633717, 
0.352203900671535, 0.205002378111855, 0.298617380108966, 0.361121346100261, 
0.357356728719259, 0.353489363645689, 0.393734182956154, 0.423315827206932, 
0.216530759330505, 0.295016729205087, 0.323374194019527, 0.343124063673784, 
0.380249052592592, 0.415107456036533, 0.396642538381016, 0.246204508799688, 
0.287056898939918, 0.290660778299961, 0.35843397096426, 0.374496993283904, 
0.408804282272156, 0.423155711438868, 0.479063817826956, 0.533346196251472, 
0.517939812787931, 0.465652751148997, 0.451015930079482, 0.406873002204554, 
0.35578784961919, 0.153763509078454, 0.278875222126368, 0.295395648504666, 
0.236747830577616, 0.192832602672177, 0.125162480857592, 0.0884593274564679, 
0.0931047982011866, 0.270228058014814, 0.28678572518987, 0.24490685305296, 
0.150225891681608, 0.088965249552683, 0.0772770149908026, 0.11498843070774, 
0.299765573725176, 0.298295657553661, 0.328834652826522, 0.252255362778831, 
0.175660266918363, 0.105961987309341, 0.170249991853749, 0.37434217820651, 
0.386086473984172, 0.360740220566506, 0.344153078269405, 0.276532261790009, 
0.254949155212946, 0.236015064565441, 0.382372773689974, 0.426957985418887, 
0.417674990415856, 0.367342502701776, 0.357347691942056, 0.318365064254725, 
0.279401224357653, 0.442861281676323, 0.466212608650452, 0.476050767425474, 
0.451262519554918, 0.396428476686235, 0.365491153293189, 0.419352310228274, 
0.497512077394271, 0.472463043552601, 0.451518340525579, 0.440030976546009, 
0.346863051112547, 0.361804433530373, 0.122189415101837, 0.262192931595117, 
0.265922660021079, 0.217004381628949, 0.181499989169302, 0.132203113207458, 
0.0593732438272885, 0.11257134996094, 0.29988027703599, 0.273795884229825, 
0.229063577458736, 0.175413341629273, 0.104997014755257, 0.000946080512442869, 
0.119776913366629, 0.338115370714483, 0.32605946248016, 0.291367206138106, 
0.265499743967985, 0.216398448337378, 0.100375563617948, 0.173488488324256, 
0.379421467199098, 0.389666392069048, 0.33685727063291, 0.327941049203604, 
0.268972618585353, 0.246646142133248, 0.212034829952889, 0.400316603589562, 
0.421104095763602, 0.410619825481875, 0.404095922513458, 0.349500567097573, 
0.284845416453197, 0.27550637506891, 0.430621861706829, 0.460427446576162, 
0.490202032731378, 0.452309009025583, 0.399112135628165, 0.347218815210686
), landscape = c("cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "cluster", 
"cluster", "cluster", "cluster", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", 
"regular", "regular", "regular", "regular", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", "random", 
"random", "random", "random", "random", "random")), row.names = c(NA, 
-147L), groups = structure(list(theta = list(`1` = 20, `2` = 40, 
    `3` = 60, `4` = 80, `5` = 100, `6` = 120, `7` = 140), .rows = structure(list(
    1:7, 8:14, 15:21, 22:28, 29:35, 36:42, 43:49), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -7L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The summary statistics appear when I run your code. What version of ggplot are you running, and is there anything else written in your error message that you have not included here?

Comment: The version is ggplot2_3.3.5, and there was only the error of bandwidth as well.

Comment: If you remove the quotation marks around `mean_sdl` do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, still receive the same error. As well as an attempt to update ggplot2. But I have admin issues making this difficult.

Comment: Do you have the function `ggplot2::mean_sdl` available? As in, when you type this into your console is the object found?

Comment: Yes, i typed into the console and it was available.

Comment: Perhaps try updating `Hmisc`?

Comment: Bingo! I installed the Hmisc package and the plot is now functioning. Brilliant.

Comment: The cryptic error message here will be improved in the next release of ggplot (>3.3.6) which should mention that a package is missing as per  this PR https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/4856

Answer (score 1):

I didnt receive this erro running your code.....

The output was this with the following message:

```
Bin width defaults to 1/30 of the range of the data. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I got the same. I'm not sure that this solves the OP's problem though.